# comprobar si un div contiene otro div concreto

Tags: javascript

Tengo tres div:

```
 <div class="global">

        <div class="content">

        </div>
</div>

<div class="global">

        <div class="content">
            <div class="imagen"></div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="global">

        <div class="content">
            <div class="resumen anchuraTotal"></div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

si en content no hay nada quiero que pinte los div imagen y resumen.
Si está la imagen pero falta el resumen, quiero que pinte el resumen.
Cuando está el resumen pero falta la imagen, por defecto inserta la clase "anchuraTotal". Tiene que quitar la clase anchura total, dejando la clase 
"resumen" y además insertar la imagen de nuevo dentro del content.
Al final todos deben quedar así:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="imagen"></div>
    <div class="resumen"></div>
</div>
```

Cuando no hay nada, consigo pintar, pero en el resto, no sé como condicionarlo porque cuando no falla uno, falla otro. Todo lo que encuentro es con jQuery y necesito que sea javascript puro.

Ayuda por favor!!

function insertCourseListContent () {

```
var globalBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("global");
var resumenDiv= document.getElementsByClassName("resumen anchuraTotal")[0];
var imagenDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("imagen")[0];

for (var i = 0; i < globalBoxes.length; i++) {

    var contentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[i];

    if (contentDiv.childElementCount < 1) {

        var resumenDiv= document.createElement("div");
        resumenDiv.setAttribute("class", "resumen");

        contentDiv.appendChild(resumenDiv);

        var imagenDiv = document.createElement("div");
        imagenDiv.setAttribute("class", "imagen");
        contentDiv.appendChild(imagenDiv);

    }
    else if (contentDiv.childElementCount == 1 && contentDiv.children[0] == resumenDiv) {

        for (var j = 0; j < resumenDiv.length; j++) {

            var anchuraTotalClase= document.getElementsByClassName("resumen anchuraTotal")[j];
            if (anchuraTotalClase!== undefined){
                anchuraTotalClase.classList.remove("anchuraTotal");
                var imagenDiv= document.createElement("div");
                imagenDiv.setAttribute("class", "imagen");
                contentDiv.appendChild(imagenDiv);

            }

        }

    }else if (contentDiv.childElementCount == 1 && contentDiv.children[0] == imagenDiv) {
        var resumenyDiv = document.createElement("div");
        resumenDiv.setAttribute("class", "resumen");

        contentDiv.appendChild(resumenDiv);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: ¿Has intentando algo? ¿Qué error tienes?

Comment: No tengo errores. Simplemente, no hace lo que quiero.

Comment: He editado la pregunta. Me gustaría comprobar si dentro de cada "content" existe una clase u otra. la que no exista, la tiene que crear. Y si existe "anchuraTotal, la tiene que eliminar...

Comment: Ya está solucionado. He utilizado querySelector. if (!contentDiv.querySelector(".resumen") && !contentDiv.querySelector(".imagen")). Luego publico la solución Gracias!!

Comment: @JorgeGarcíaCano creo que puedes dejar la respuesta abierta por si alguien le interesa hallar una solución simplificando el código.

Comment: De acuerdo. Entonces... No contesto a mi pregunta ?? la vuelvo a editar?? o puedo contestar sin que se cierre?

Comment: @JorgeGarcíaCano de hecho, creo que hay una medalla si contestas tu misma pregunta: "Autodidacta" [Todas las medallas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2699/lista-de-todas-las-medallas-con-su-descripci%C3%B3n-completa)

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que he hecho y funciona. Si alguien quiere aportar se agradece. Muchas gracias como siempre!!!

```
var resumenDiv= document.getElementsByClassName("resumen anchuraTotal");
var imagenDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("imagen");
var globalBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("global")[0];

for (var i = 0; i < globalBoxes.children.length; i++) {

  var contentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[i];

    if (!contentDiv.querySelector(".resumen") && !contentDiv.querySelector(".imagen")){

                var resumenDiv = document.createElement("div");
                resumenDiv.setAttribute("class", "resumen");
                contentDiv.appendChild(resumenDiv);
                var imagenDiv = document.createElement("div");
                imagenDiv.setAttribute("class", "imagen");
                contentDiv.appendChild(imagenDiv);

    }
    else if (!contentDiv.querySelector(".resumen") && contentDiv.querySelector(".imagen"))
    {
                 var resumenDiv = document.createElement("div");
                 resumenDiv.setAttribute("class", "resumen");
                 contentDiv.appendChild(resumenDiv);

     }
     else if (contentDiv.querySelector(".resumen") && !contentDiv.querySelector(".imagen")) 
     {
                 var anchuraTotalClase= document.getElementsByClassName("resumen anchuraTotal")[0];

                 if (anchuraTotal!== undefined){

                     anchuraTotalClase.classList.remove("anchuraTotal");
                     var imagenDiv= document.createElement("div");
                     imagenDiv.setAttribute("class", "imagen");
                     contentDiv.appendChild(imagenDiv);
                  }
      }

}
```